# Create XCFramework out of two static libraries (libssl.a, libcrypto.a)

Tags: ios, openssl, static-libraries, libcrypto, xcframework

Consider OpenSSL, the project itself has two products: `libssl.a` and `libcrypto.a`.
For the sake of simplicity, let's use the precompiled libraries stored [in this repository](https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/OpenSSL) and consider just `iphonesimulator` platform.

When looking at the repository, each platform, e.g. `iphonesimulator` or `iphoneos` will have a set of static libraries for all of the architectures needed.

My goal is to create an XCFramework that bundles those two static libraries, so that it would be convenient to use with Swift Package Manager as a single package.

I definitely can create an XCFramework supporting multiple platforms: iOS Simulator (`i386`, `x86_64`, `arm64`), iOS (`arm64`, `arm7`...) from static libraries with the following command:

```
xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
-library iphonesimulator/lib/libcrypto.a \
-headers iphonesimulator/include/ \
-library iphoneos/lib/libcrypto.a \
-headers iphoneos/include/ \
-output OpenSSL.xcframework
```

The output is as follows:

> xcframework successfully written out to:
> /Users/name/OSSL_test/OpenSSL.xcframework

The structure of the framework is correct and it contains both headers and the `libcrypto.a`. When imported into another Xcode project, this XCFramework is recognized and used in building an app.

However, when I also try to add `libssl.a`, I get the following error:

```
xcodebuild -create-xcframework \
-library iphonesimulator/lib/libcrypto.a \
-headers iphonesimulator/include/ \
-library iphonesimulator/lib/libssl.a \
-headers iphonesimulator/include/ \
-output OpenSSL.xcframework
```

> A library with the identifier "ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator"
> already exists.

Which makes sense, since both `libcrypto.a` and `libssl.a` are of the same architecture.

So, my question is, is it possible to bundle two static libraries together using a single XCFramework? Or should I create two separate XCFrameworks, so that each library has it's own?

In the repository mentioned above, the static library actually used in another build phase as inputs producing a `.framework` per each platform. The build logic is in the `OpenSSL.xcodeproj`. So, I assume, what I'm asking is simply not possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You basically have two options:

1. Create two separate XCFrameworks, one for `libcrypto.a` and one for `libssl.a`, **or**
2. Combine `libcrypto.a` and `libssl.a` into a single library, let's say, `libOpenSSL.a` and use this combined library to create a single XCFramework.

It looks like you know how to do (1). So what do you need to do for (2)?

You can create a combined libOpenSSL.a by doing the following (best to copy the libraries to a clean tmp directory for this):

```sh
ar -x libcrypto.a
ar -x libssl.a
ar -cr libOpenSSL.a *.o
```

The first two commands extract all the object files from each of `libcrypto.a` and `libssl.a` and the final command creates the new combined static library.

**Update:**
User Steven0351 let me know in a comment that there is a more elegant way of achieving the same result as the sequence of `ar` commands above using `libtool`:

```
libtool -static -o libOpenSSL.a libcrypto.a libssl.a
```

A word of caution... If you have been using GNU tools you need to make sure that the `libtool` you run is the one in Xcode toolchain. So you may want to prefix the above with `xcrun`.

Comment: Getting this error: ar -x libcrypto.a
ar: libcrypto.a is a fat file (use libtool(1) or lipo(1) and ar(1) on it)
ar: libcrypto.a: Inappropriate file type or format


So I have to extract each slice individually, but technically your suggestion should work! Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned  that. You need to combine the non-fat .a files first and then use lipo.

Comment: Yep, feel free to add this to your answer. The idea is still correct - it's possible to add multiple static libraries into a single XCFramework.

Comment: Just an FYI, you can also do the same thing with libtool without having to manually extract the archives: `libtool -static -o outputname.a list.a of.a archives.a`

Comment: @Steven0351 - I did not know that! I will update the answer. I always though this was a bit ugly.