# Cocoapod with prebuilt static libraries for the same architecture but different platforms (ios and ios simulator)

Tags: ios, cocoapods, ios-simulator, podspec, xcframework

We have this podspec referring a static library with `spec.vendored_libraries` . The static library was build for 2 cases:

- arm64, ios
- arm64, ios-simulator

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
    spec.platform                 = :ios
    spec.name                     = 'pod_lib'
    spec.version                  = '1.0.0'
    spec.homepage                 = 'pod_lib'
    spec.source                   = { :git => "Not Published", :tag => "Cocoapods/#{spec.name}/#{spec.version}" }
    spec.authors                  = 'Authors'
    spec.license                  = ''
    spec.summary                  = 'pod_lib'
    spec.ios.deployment_target    = '13.5'
    spec.source_files             = 'headers/**/*.h'
    spec.public_header_files      = 'headers/**/*.h'
    spec.vendored_libraries       = 'iosArm64/lib/a.a'
    spec.header_mappings_dir      = 'headers'
    spec.static_framework         = true
    spec.libraries                = 'c++'
    spec.pod_target_xcconfig      = {
    'CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD' => 'c++20',
    'CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY' => 'libc++',
    'ARCHS' => 'arm64',
    }
end
```

Is it possible to specify both libraries in the cocoapod podspec?

I would like to have something like

```
    spec.vendored_libraries       = 'iosArm64/lib/a.a',
                                    'iosSimulatorArm64/lib/a.a'
```

This does not work because of the same names of the libs and it seems as such functionality is not yet supported: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/8688

As a workaround some people propose to use `lipo` to build a universal binary:

`lipo -create -output libuniversal.a ./iosArm64/lib/a.a ./iosSimulatorArm64/lib/a.a`

This does not work because both binaries are already built for the same architecture (arm64).

Is it possible to have one cocoapod that includes both platforms? Or is there another approach to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the link below the usage of `ar` or `libtool` is described to make a universal static library, which then can be wrapped into a XCFramework for both iOS and iOS-Simulator platform

See ... [Create XCFramework out of two static libraries (libssl.a, libcrypto.a)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67877518/create-xcframework-out-of-two-static-libraries-libssl-a-libcrypto-a)

Answer (score 0):

The problem of supporting multiple platforms with the same architectures is why Apple created the XCFramework construct. Details at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating-a-multi-platform-binary-framework-bundle